# Influxdb 100% CPU Load and keeps restarting

Tags: influxdb

My influxdb instance causes 100% CPU Load und keeps on restarting...

InfluxDB v2.4.0 (git: de247bab08) build_date: 2022-08-18T19:41:15Z
I migrated from 1.x to 2.x before, but it was running fine for a few weeks.

I had 100% cpu load before and rebooting fixed the problem.
But now it doesn't.

This is what the Log says

```
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.045061Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/423/000000002-000000002.tsm id=0 duration=1.226ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.045945Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open index_version=tsi1 path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/423 duration=147.782ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: InfluxDB API at http://localhost:8086/ready unavailable after 53 attempts...
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.112610Z lvl=info msg="index opened with 8 partitions" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine index=tsi
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.157515Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/3979/000000001-000000001.tsm id=0 duration=3.233ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.160292Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open index_version=tsi1 path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/3979 duration=193.720ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.228938Z lvl=info msg="index opened with 8 partitions" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine index=tsi
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.238679Z lvl=info msg="index opened with 8 partitions" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine index=tsi
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.239940Z lvl=info msg="index opened with 8 partitions" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine index=tsi
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.245667Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/4230/000000002-000000002.tsm id=0 duration=1.871ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.246436Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open index_version=tsi1 path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/4230 duration=217.347ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.267353Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/3981/000000002-000000002.tsm id=0 duration=0.406ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.268150Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open index_version=tsi1 path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/3981 duration=225.899ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.276942Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/4232/000000001-000000001.tsm id=0 duration=2.305ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.278232Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open index_version=tsi1 path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/4232 duration=232.152ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.293604Z lvl=info msg="index opened with 8 partitions" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine index=tsi
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.300673Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/3983/000000002-000000002.tsm id=0 duration=0.658ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.303627Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open index_version=tsi1 path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/3983 duration=142.882ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.362917Z lvl=info msg="index opened with 8 partitions" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine index=tsi
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.380454Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/4234/000000001-000000001.tsm id=0 duration=0.990ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.381306Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open index_version=tsi1 path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/4234 duration=134.630ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.443019Z lvl=info msg="index opened with 8 partitions" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine index=tsi
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.461259Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/3987/000000002-000000002.tsm id=0 duration=1.076ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.462142Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open index_version=tsi1 path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/3987 duration=155.574ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.476794Z lvl=info msg="index opened with 8 partitions" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine index=tsi
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.481707Z lvl=info msg="index opened with 8 partitions" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine index=tsi
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.506325Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/3985/000000001-000000001.tsm id=0 duration=1.228ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.507162Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open index_version=tsi1 path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/3985 duration=238.842ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.518333Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/4236/000000002-000000002.tsm id=0 duration=7.912ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.519170Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open index_version=tsi1 path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/4236 duration=240.810ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.622377Z lvl=info msg="index opened with 8 partitions" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine index=tsi
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.636355Z lvl=info msg="index opened with 8 partitions" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine index=tsi
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.658833Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/4238/000000002-000000002.tsm id=0 duration=1.797ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.661254Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open index_version=tsi1 path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/4238 duration=279.787ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.670331Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/3989/000000001-000000001.tsm id=0 duration=0.592ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.674528Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open index_version=tsi1 path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/3989 duration=212.245ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.682649Z lvl=info msg="index opened with 8 partitions" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine index=tsi
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.727290Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/4240/000000002-000000002.tsm id=0 duration=1.604ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.728159Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open index_version=tsi1 path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/4240 duration=208.846ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.852231Z lvl=info msg="index opened with 8 partitions" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine index=tsi
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.885201Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/399/000000003-000000002.tsm id=0 duration=14.223ms
Aug 22 15:00:04 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:04.887978Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open index_version=tsi1 path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/399 duration=380.574ms
Aug 22 15:00:05 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:05.005108Z lvl=info msg="index opened with 8 partitions" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine index=tsi
Aug 22 15:00:05 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:05.011388Z lvl=info msg="index opened with 8 partitions" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine index=tsi
Aug 22 15:00:05 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:05.025174Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/4242/000000001-000000001.tsm id=0 duration=2.749ms
Aug 22 15:00:05 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:05.026069Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open index_version=tsi1 path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/4242 duration=349.790ms
Aug 22 15:00:05 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:05.028960Z lvl=info msg="Opened file" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 service=filestore path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/3991/000000001-000000001.tsm id=0 duration=5.543ms
Aug 22 15:00:05 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:05.044621Z lvl=info msg="Opened shard" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine service=store op_name=tsdb_open index_version=tsi1 path=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data/bdba728d0330eeac/autogen/3991 duration=381.629ms
Aug 22 15:00:05 APU influxd-systemd-start.sh[31144]: ts=2022-08-22T13:00:05.102276Z lvl=info msg="index opened with 8 partitions" log_id=0cTQ00ll000 service=storage-engine index=tsi
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a Solution [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/influxdb/comments/pbqwh2/cant_get_influxdb_to_start/):

Try this:

> 1. Edit the file /etc/systemd/system/influxd.service
> 2. Find the line "Type=forking" and comment it out by putting a '#" in front:
>    Restart=on-failure
>    #Type=forking
>    PIDFile=/var/lib/influxdb/influxd.pid
> 3. sudo systemctl daemon-reload
> 4. Now you should be able to "sudo systemctl start influxdb"

Comment: this does not work for me :'-( Clearly, influxd is trying to restart, as lines with `Feb 04 10:29:00 rpi-name influxd-systemd-start.sh[2837]: InfluxDB API unavailable after X attempts...` keep showing up in the log every now and then.